# Python: Install local package in a docker container in site-packages folder

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I need to install a local package (my own shared package) in a docker container, but it doesn't work without `-e` option.

I've the following:

**Docker folder tree:**

```
./
├── Dockerfile
├── mypackage-lib
│   ├── MANIFEST.in
│   ├── mypackagelib
│   └── setup.py
├── requirements.txt
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3 


# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/

# copy requirements file
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/requirements.txt
COPY ./mypackage-lib /usr/src/mypackage-lib

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install -e /usr/src/mypackage-lib

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```

pip freeze from the docker container:

```
# Editable install with no version control (mypackagelib==0.1)
-e /usr/src/mypackage-lib
```

I would like to have it in the `site-packages` directory and not linked from `/usr/src/mypackage-lib`

Without the option `-e` the main application (which is using the library) doesn't work.

`setup.py` looks like:

```
install_requires = [
        'pydantic'
    ]

setup(name='mypackagelib',
    version='0.1',
    author='aemilc',
    packages=['mypackagelib'],
    install_requires=install_requires,
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires='>3.8')
```

What did I forget?

Thank you!

E.